# Type error : e is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting a type error: e undefined on the javascript code. I am trying to populate a dropdown list using jquery with data sent from a mysql server.

here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){// This script uses jquery and ajax it is used to set the values in
$("#day").change(function(){// the time field whenever a day is selected.
    var day=$("#day").val();
    var doctor=$("#doctor").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"time.php",
        data:"day="+day+"&doctor="+doctor,
        dataType : 'json',
        success:function(data){
            var option = '';
            $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
                console.log(data.d);
                option += '<option>' + value.arr + '</option>';
            });
            $('#timing').html(option);
        }

    });
});
});
```

Here's the php script which fetches data from a mysql database

```
$doctor = $_POST['doctor'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$query="SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE doctor='$doctor' AND day='$day'";
$arr = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$i = 0; 
//Initialize the variable which passes over the array key values
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    //Fetches an associative array of the row
$index = array_keys($row);             // Fetches an array of keys for the row.
while($row[$index[$i]] != NULL)
{
    if($row[$index[$i]] == 1) {
        //$res = $index[$i];
        //echo json_encode($res);
        array_push($arr, $index[$res]);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: which line are you getting the error on? Also where are you getting the `index` and `value` from?

Comment: I don't see any part in your code currently which could cause this error in an obvious way. Either you are missing the crucial line, or the error is raised in the underlying framework (jquery).

Comment: in data, use data : {doctor:doctorVal,day:dayValue}

Comment: replace variables with values in your SELECT statement and see what's in result...

Comment: In which browser you are testing it? and what is its version?

Comment: @Christoph I am getting an error on line 4 of jquery.min.js

Comment: @Mr_Green Firefox default browser for ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

You are not using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in a right way replace the line

```
$.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
```

by

```
if(data.d)
{
    $(data.d).each(function(index, value) {
       // your code
```

**Also** in **php**  use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to make **your data** as **json**

```
} // end of while
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Updated code,** try in your **php script**,

```
$i = 0; 
//Initialize the variable which passes over the array key values
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $arr['d'][$i]=$row['doctor'];
    // you can add more fields in array like above
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
return;
```

**And** in your **Javascript** it will work after reading DOC [jquery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
 $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
      option += '<option>' + value+ '</option>';
 });
```

Comment: OP should use $.each() not $(object).each()

Comment: Thanks! :).
but the log shows 
[null, null, null ..so on]

Comment: @A.Wolff But I read http://api.jquery.com/each/ and there is no `description` for **second parameter in each function**

Comment: $.each function DOC is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/  Your previous link point to $().each() method

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok I updated my answer once again, after looking the above url you given. Thanks to use `each` in a different way.

Comment: Thanks again :) now I am getting values in callback. but still the list is not populating. Could you help me out here?

Comment: @Ajit I have updated my answer once again, if it not works then try your logic to extract `options` from `json` or show us the `json` which you `get`.

Comment: [null,null,"9 to 9:30","9:30 to 10","10 to 10:30","10:30 to 11","11 to 11:30","11:30 to 12","12 to 12:30","12:30 to 1","2 to 2:30","2:30 to 3","3 to 3:30","3-30 to 4","4 to 4:30","4:30 to 5"]
This the result of my json. It's not showing in the options.

Comment: @Ajit take a look on http://jsfiddle.net/DXwQK/

Comment: @Rohan Thanks a lot. I think I have an awful lot to learn . But you saved my life today :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're not parsing your JSON, try the following, note the line

`data = JSON.parse(data);`

You must use JSON.parse on your data object otherwise JavaScript will treat it as a string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){// This script uses jquery and ajax it is used to set the values in
$("#day").change(function(){// the time field whenever a day is selected.
  var day=$("#day").val();
  var doctor=$("#doctor").val();

  $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"time.php",
      data:"day="+day+"&doctor="+doctor,
      dataType : 'json',
      success:function(data){
      var option = '';

      data = JSON.parse(data);

      $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {

      console.log(data.d);
          option += '<option>' + value.arr + '</option>';

         });

     $('#timing').html(option);
        }

       });
```

Comment: It says syntax error JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: @Ajit see at Rohan Kumar's answer, are you encoding to json the array in PHP?

Comment: Yes I did. But still show's a parse error on JSON.parse. even though  instead of null there are values in json callback. Strange